# angular.dart - watching controller for shadow DOM element ready?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I know your NgComponent can extend NgShadowRootAware...but I couldn't seem to get the same affect with my controller.

I watched a variable in the scope hoping that things would be ready by then, but they weren't. The problem is I have my template hiding HTML until an async call for data is complete. Then it shows the HTML populated with data from the API call. I want to bind an event listener to an input element within that hidden HTML.

I suppose I could create another component, but I feel that it's a little silly given it's specifically within the controller, related to the controller, not going to be anywhere else, and is only one tiny input element.

I did an empty $watch and just kept trying to set the input element and sure it's there on the last digest, but that seems a bit inefficient. Is this my only option?

Here's some code:

```dart
<div ng-if="!ctrl.assetsLoaded">
  <span class="loading-message">{{ctrl.message}}</span>
</div>

<div ng-if="ctrl.assetsLoaded">

  <nav id="controls">
    <div class="asset-actions">
      <a href="#/" class="home-folder"></a>
      <div class="folder-path">...</div>

      <span class="create-asset choose-file">
        <input type="file" id="single-file" name="file" ng-model="singleFile" />
      </span>
      <a href="#/addFolder" class="create-folder"></a>
      <search-asset name-filter-string="ctrl.nameFilter" class="search-asset"></search-asset>
    </div>
```

Essentially, I'm after the input element inside the ng-if. I want to watch when that changes. I'm now thinking ng-model (instead of Dart's event listener), but I'm just running into confusion coming from AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` instead of `ng-if`? `ng-if` literally removes the nodes from DOM tree. This may have unwanted consequences (i.e. your listeners lost, etc). `ng-show/ng-hide` just show and hide the dom nodes, they don't get removed. In your case, I don't see you would notice a lot of performance difference and your code would be a lot less messier.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
<input type="file" id="single-file" name="file" ng-model="ctrl.singleFile" />
```

and on your controller you make singleFile a getter/setter where you can add your code on the setter which is executed every time the input value changes.

Comment: Just trying to watch for an input element change (that isn't on the page immediately / shadow dom) from the controller. I'm now thinking maybe using a model. It's more Angular-y to do that rather than use Dart's event listeners.

Comment: Cool, I was getting to that point but was then confused about the model getter/setter part. Is there any good examples out there I can reference?

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm not sure it works with file input types...It works fine with text...But I can't get this working with file.

Comment: No, I haven't. What's the problem? What datatype did you use for the getter/setter. Have you tried without one (dynamic)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to return anything. But if the input type is text, I can see the value no problem. What I did instead was create a directive. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but creating a directive was simple enough. Though given it's not being re-used, I don't see the point of a directive...But was far easier.

Comment: No prob if it's not reused.